# How to call a function when the user POSTs an image in django rest api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making a face detection api that will take image as an input from a user. How can i call a function when the user creates a POST request?
I have the face detection code that was made using opencv i want to integrate it in my api.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

from .validators import validate_file_extension
def scramble_uploaded_filename(instance,filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]

    reformated = "{}.{}".format(uuid.uuid4(),extension)

    return reformated

def scramble_uploaded_filename1(instance,filename):
    extension = filename.split(".")[-1]

    return "{}.{}".format(uuid.uuid4(),extension)

class UploadVideo(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField('Uploaded Video',upload_to=scramble_uploaded_filename1, validators=[validate_file_extension] )
class UploadImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField('Uploaded Image', upload_to=scramble_uploaded_filename)
```

## urls.py in resp api

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from imageupload_rest.viewsets import UploadImageViewSet, UploadVideoViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('images', UploadImageViewSet, 'images')
router.register('videos', UploadVideoViewSet, 'videos')
app_name = 'reviews'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',include(router.urls)),
]
```

## serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from imageupload.models import UploadImage, UploadVideo

class UploadImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadImage
        fields = ('pk', 'image', )

class UploadVideoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadVideo
        fields = ('pk', 'video' , )
```

## viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from imageupload_rest.serializers import UploadImageSerializer, UploadVideoSerializer
from imageupload.models import UploadImage, UploadVideo

class UploadImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = UploadImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadImageSerializer

class UploadVideoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UploadVideo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadVideoSerializer
```

## imagefunction.py this is stored in the same folder as viewsets

```
#when the user posts an image this function should run
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
def image(path):
    recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    #trainingData.yml is my pretrained model which includes a unique id for each user
    recognizer.read('recognizer/trainingData.yml')
    detector = `cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades\data\haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')`   
    im = cv2.imread(path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (225, 0, 0), 2)
        Id, conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])
        if 2 < conf < 125:
            cv2.putText(im, str(Id), (x, y + h),fontface, fontscale, fontcolor)
    cv2.imshow('Recognition', im)
    cv2.imwrite("image.jpg",im)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    res = "true"
    return res
```

I want this function to run after the user POSTs an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using `modelViewset` you need to overwrite existing `post` method of modelViewset life-cycle method. check [CreateAPIView](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py)

```
from .imagefunction import image
from rest_framework import status

class UploadImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UploadImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UploadImageSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
         serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
         self.perform_create(serializer)
         // call your image recognition funciton, what should response some thing 
         is_face_include = image(serializer.data.get('image')) // or may be image(serializer.data.get('image')).url 
         if is_face_include: // we need our success method 
            return Response({message: "succesfully upload image"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
         else:
            Response({message: "no face found"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: can you please give me an example of how I will put a function in that post function? for example, I want to print "I did it" after the user posts an image.  I am new to APIs as I just started learning it for my high school project.  Thanks in advance :D

Comment: you just simply call that function like any other function call in python. Please update your question with your desire function ( also where it is ) so that that i can give you complete code.

Comment: i added the imagefunction.py that should run when the user posts an image. also the path that it takes is the path of the image that the user has posted. all the images file are stored in the folder called "uploaded_media"

Comment: @daduboi i have updated my response. make sure your image method return something so that from view we can decide what to give response.